# Solving Nonlinear Nonlocal Schrodinger equation when the nonlinear term is spatially nonlocal

Tags: algorithm, matlab, numerical-methods, pde, nonlinear-functions

The standard NLSE is:

```
i du/dt+1/2 d^2u/dx^2+|u|^2u = 0
```

One of the methods solving it is, say,Pseudo-spectral method:

```
  L=80; N=2048; dt=0.0001; tmax=20; nmax=round(tmax/dt);
  dx=L/N; x=[-L/2:dx:L/2-dx]'; k=[0:N/2-1 -N/2:-1]'*2*pi/L; k2=k.^2;
  u=1.2*sech(1.2*(x+20)).*exp(i*x)+0.8*sech(0.8*x);
  udata=u; tdata=0;
  for nn=1:nmax                               % integration begins
  du1=1i*(ifft(-k2.*fft(u))+2*u.*u.*conj(u));  v=u+0.5*du1*dt;
  du2=1i*(ifft(-k2.*fft(v))+2*v.*v.*conj(v));  v=u+0.5*du2*dt;
  du3=1i*(ifft(-k2.*fft(v))+2*v.*v.*conj(v));  v=u+    du3*dt;
  du4=1i*(ifft(-k2.*fft(v))+2*v.*v.*conj(v));
  u=u+(du1+2*du2+2*du3+du4)*dt/6;
  if mod(nn,round(nmax/25)) == 0
   udata=[udata u]; tdata=[tdata nn*dt];
  end
  end                                         % integration ends
  mesh(x, tdata, abs(udata'));           % solution plotting
  colormap('jet'); view(10, 60)
  grid on
  text(-2,  -6, 'x', 'fontsize', 15)
  text(50, 5, 't', 'fontsize', 15)
  zlabel('|u|', 'fontsize', 15)
  axis([-L/2 L/2 0 tmax 0 2]); grid off
  set(gca, 'xtick', [-40 -20 0 20 40])
  set(gca, 'ytick', [0 10 20])
  set(gca, 'ztick', [0 1 2])
```

In MATLAB the nonlinear term in standard NLSE reads as

```
u(x,t).*conj(u(x,t)).*u(x,t).
```

Now in nonlocal NLSE the same nonlinear term is :

```
u(x,t).*conj(u(-x,t)).*u(x,t)
```

with a '-' sign in `conj(u(x,t))`.

Now my question is:
In *NONLOCAL NLSE* how the code is going to change, more specifically how the '-' sign of the nonlinear term is going to be taken care of in line marked as `13, 14 ,15, 16, 17, 18`?

Comment: Is this code supposed to be runnable? Apparently it contains an error in the loop (at "Line 13")

Comment: To embert:
Now I have given a different code which uses pseudo-spectral method to solve NLSE . It is running okay in MATLAB. See the code in the question above. Now, can you tell me how to solve the nonlocal NLSE using this method where now there is '-x' in the argument of u and v i.e. conj(u(-x,t)) and conj(v(-x,t)) in the nonlinear term? Maybe we need to change something in the for loop as marked by the comment "the integration begins" portion.
Regards,
Samit